# How to change the Product NAME and SKU permanently in quote_item table when it is added to cart?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quote, sku, quoteitem

How to do this? I am using `checkout_cart_product_add_after`  event.

EDIT:

After I did it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
      <observer name="changesku" instance="Vdndor\ProductChanger\Observer\ChangeSKU" />
  </event>
</config>
```

and Observer as

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductChanger\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class ChangeSKU implements ObserverInterface
{
    
      /**
     * Below is the method that will fire whenever the event runs!
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quoteItem = $event->getQuoteItem();

        $quoteItem->setSKU('SAMPLE');
        $quoteItem->setName("SAMPLE NAME");

        
    }
}
```

But still it is changing the SKU and NAME in **quote_item** table perfectly when I add it to cart. But whenever I go the cart page or I place the order the old NAME and SKU are saving back. any help?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following one for `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event

```
class Mynamespace_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesQuoteItemSetProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        //only change the item you want by product id
        if($item->getProductId() == "abc"){
            $item->setName('Custom Product Name');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mitul Vadalia... I tried ur approach for the same event you suggested too. but it is not changing the name permanently. That is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an around plugin on the save method of the following repositories:

- \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface
- \Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface

Something like:

```
public function aroundSave(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository, 
        callable $proceed, 
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem
    ) {
        $cartItem->setSku('YOUR SKU');
        return $proceed;
    }
```

Another solution is to add a preference for the same repositories, inherit original class and add a new implementation for the save method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what is callable $proceed here? if I have to use if statement to set it for a particular SKU product... how should I write it?

Comment: Need to add a plugin, there are more info on Magento's documentation: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/